# jquery validate() returning undefined

Tags: jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the Validate plugin for Jquery just to validate one field. I can get it working on a simple test form but when I tried to plug it into a large existing form on my site, calling `validate` returns `undefined`.  It's supposed to return a `Validator` object.  How do I go about figuring out what's wrong?

Here is the example code that's working:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function tst(ctrl) {
    var frm = $(ctrl).parents('form');
    alert('Is email valid? ' + frm.validate({ showErrors: function () { } }).element(ctrl));
}
</script>
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" onblur="tst(this)" class="email"/>
</form>
```

However if I try this on a much larger existing form, the `validate` call returns undefined, resulting in a JavaScript error calling `element`.  I think there must be something in the larger form that makes `validate` "crash", but what could it be?

Comment: Your actual question "How do I go about figuring out what's wrong?" might start with actually posting/showing the code that fails not what works.

Answer (score 5):

[`.valiate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) doesn't return a boolean, it *sets up* validation.

To determine whether a `<form>` or input element is valid you call [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to get a boolean result. Make sure to call this *after* `.validate()`, since there will be no validator setup on the `<form>` otherwise.

Comment: I edited my question.  But it still should not return undefined.

Comment: @JoelFan - You'll need to show your code...for example are you calling it on a `<form>`? it's not valid otherwise.

Comment: @JoelFan - it's *not* returning `undefined`, you're calling `.element()` that's giving `undefined`, see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VJt3w/ The problem is that element has no rules, if you gave it rules you'd get a boolean, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VJt3w/1/

Comment: @Nick, it *is* returning undefined. It never calls `element`... instead it gets a JavaScript error about `validate` returning `undefined`.  The element does have a rule because its class is `email`... Just to be clear... the code in the question *does* work... it's only when I try it in a larger form that the `undefined` problem happens

Comment: @JoelFan - If you're not posting code with the actual issue...no one can help you really, you're basically saying "I have this problem...here's some code that doesn't at all show the problem"...why add the code?

Comment: @Nick, I guess I'm just asking... what are the things that would cause `validate` to return `undefined`?

Comment: @JoelFan - Are you sure you're calling it on a `<form>` element?

Comment: I'm calling it on: $(ctrl).parents('form') which is a jQuery selection containing the form

Answer (score 0):

did you try using JQuery object..
instead of `var frm`, using `var $frm`:

```
var $frm = $(ctrl).parents('form');
alert('Is email valid? ' + $frm.validate({ showErrors: function () { } }).element(ctrl));
```

when you set `frm` without `$` you would just store the html element in a pure javascript variable, not getting the element in a JQuery object..